# Entity Framework 6, Repository Pattern, Unit of Work, Save and get last ID and then update record

Tags: entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have taken over a MVC web project which uses EF6, Repository pattern, unit of work. I'm just starting to learn EF6.

I would like to create a new organisation and save it to the database and then get the new organisation id. The new organisation id is going to be used to rename an image file which will be stored in organisation.logo. Then update the organisation logo field in the database with the new file name.

I have the organisation saving, getting the new organisation ID, renaming the file but I cannot get the logo field to update?

Code below:

Organisation Controller - Basic code is shown I have removed alot of validation and renaming the image file.

```
public ActionResult Create(OrganisationViewModel viewModelToCreate)
    {

        Organisation newOrganisation = new Organisation();
        newOrganisation.Name = viewModelToCreate.Name;
        newOrganisation.Logo = "To Change";

        _Uow.OrganisationRepository.InsertOrUpdate(newOrganisation);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _Uow.Save();
            int newOrganisationId = _Uow.OrganisationRepository.LastInsertedID();
            Organisation organisationToUpdate = _Uow.OrganisationRepository.Find(newOrganisationId);
string fileName = newOrganisationId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(viewModelToCreate.FileNameToAdd.FileName);

                organisationToUpdate.Logo = fileName;
                _Uow.OrganisationRepository.InsertOrUpdate(organisationToUpdate);
                _Uow.Save();
            }

    }


public virtual T InsertOrUpdate(T e)
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = Context.Set<T>();

        DbEntityEntry<T> entry;
        if (e.ID != default(int))
        {
            entry = Context.Entry(e);

        }
        else
        {
            T instance = dbSet.Create();
            instance.ID = e.ID;
            entry = Context.Entry(instance);
            dbSet.Attach(instance);
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(e);
            e = instance;
        }

        entry.State = e.ID == default(int) ?
                                EntityState.Added :
                                EntityState.Modified;

        return e;
    }


     int IUnitOfWork.Save()
        {

                return _Context.SaveChanges();
     }

      public int LastInsertedID()
         {
             Context = new aContext();
             int newOrganisationId = Context.Organisations.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault().ID;
             return newOrganisationId;
    }
```

How do I update the organisationToUpdate.Logo with the new filename, it does not save to the database?

Comment: Why don't you set `newOrganisation.Logo`?

Comment: I've tried that and it still does not work.

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Hard to imagine that that would insert an `Organisation` without a logo.

Comment: Update my code to reply to @GertArnold thanks.

Comment: So you're saying the new organization row is inserted with a NULL in the column mapped to the Logo property?

Comment: @JonasHøgh no, on the initial insert into the database i have added a string. Its inserts fine. I then get the new id of the inserted record. I would like to update the logo field with the new filename and save it. I have debugged it all and The new file name works and also saves to file storage in azure. The record will not update with the new value?

Comment: Can you show the code of repo.InsertOrUpdate and uow.Save?

Comment: Where is this `"To Change"` value set? I bet it happens somewhere in `InsertOrUpdate`.

Comment: @GertArnold I updated the controller code to demonstrate. Thanks

Comment: So again, why don't you set `newOrganisation.Logo`? I.e. `newOrganisation.Logo = fileName;`.

Comment: Because I need to rename the filename to the organisation id. I can't get the new organisation ID until it is saved?

Comment: You don't need these two line:  int newOrganisationId = _Uow.OrganisationRepository.LastInsertedID();
            Organisation organisationToUpdate = _Uow.OrganisationRepository.Find(newOrganisationId);  - You can keep updating newOrganisation. And please share the body of these functions: LastInsertedID, InsertOrUpdate, and Save

Comment: It's hard to say how your predecessor managed to make everything so complicated for himself, but I'd advise you to get rid of both his UOW and repositories and just use your class derived from DbContext directly. As rad describes, updating an entity should be as simple as loading it from the context, assigning the new property value(s) and calling SaveChanges. It looks like something is fundamentally broken, are you maybe using an incorrectly configured IoC container, causing the different classes to uses different instances of your context class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared your UoW and Repository methods we cannot know what exactly is happening in your code. However, I provided the required code that do what you need without considering the Repository and UoW. Just check if your code is doing the following:

```
var db = new AppDbContext();

// inserting new organization
Organisation newOrganisation = new Organisation();
newOrganisation.Name = viewModelToCreate.Name;
newOrganisation.Logo = "To Change";
db.Organisation.Add(newOrganisation);
db.SaveChanges();

// updating the inserted organization
string fileName = ”New FileName”;
newOrganisation.Logo = fileName;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Apologies, I had updated my code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You need two calls to your [UOW.Save] method. Call the first one like you are. When you've done that, the entity you saved will be updated with its Id that was assigned in the database. Then add code which takes that Id and appends it your filename as you need. If that doesnt work, theres something wrong with your UOW or Repository that is preventing it from working correctly. As an aside, UOW and Repository are "patterns" not implementations, so we cant be expected to know what that code looks like and how it works, you need to be more specific about exactly what you're doing, if you want the question answered

Comment: Apologies, I had updated my code in the original question